Python - MetaTrader5 Library: Functions are not recognized
In Windows 11, I installed the current version of python ( 3.12.4 ), and the latest version of MetaTarder5, using pip install MetaTrader5.
In PyCharm, I imported it using import MetaTrader5 as mt5, and when I try to call any function from the documentation, for example: mt5.login(); mt5.initialize(), it does not recognize it.
import MetaTrader5 as mt5

mt5.login()  # Cannot find reference 'login' in '__init__.py'

I tried also older version of MetaTrader5 and numpy, same result

When I was trying to set this up, I had to 1) Create and activate a venv, 2) run python -m pip install MetaTrader5, and 3) run python -m pip install numpy<2, then run the program with the venv activated. That was sufficient for me; I don't know what's happening in your case.

what version of Python?

I'm using version 3.12.3.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

@furas There wasn't a traceback IIRC. It was just alt-text in PyCharm.

where did you get this text? Maybe PyCharm was wrong. Did you run code?

BTW: I found some [example](login - Python Integration - MQL5 Reference - Reference on algorithmic/automated trading language for MetaTrader 5) and it starts with mt5.initialize(). Maybe it needs it to make connection with program MetaTrader and maybe it adds function(s) dynamically (using some C/C++ library).

I made it work, I follow your instruction, I installed Python 3.12.3, because I had 3.12.4. After that, I tried with the latest version of MetaTrader5, but same result, the functions weren't found, and I installed one older version and run: pip install MetaTrader5==5.0.4288; I installed numpy<2, and now everything work fine. But still I do not know why latest version of MetaTrader5 doesn't worked.

The latest version was release around 1 week ago, I think is a bug or something

you could send this information to author(s). Maybe they have some repo on GitHub with place for issues. BTW: it shows that sometimes it better to use little older versions because they are better tested or authors had time to make version which can work with new functionality in (little older) Python.

I encountered issues with the latest version of MetaTrader5 and numpy but resolved them by downgrading to the following:
MetaTrader5: Version 5.0.4288 (previous version)
numpy: Version 1.26.4 (ensure it's < 2.0)

It seems the newer versions might have compatibility issues. Reverting to these specific versions worked perfectly for me. If you're facing similar problems, try using these versions to see if it resolves your issue.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
